# Code First EF save extended entity >> The entity type xxx is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am new to EF.
I extended an entity with new properties only needed in the controller.
When I save the entity, I don't need the properties anymore and `upcasted` to the base entity and tried to save, but every time I got the error:

> The entity type XXX is not part of the model for the current context.

The attribute `[NotMapped]` did not work either (on class and / or property).

How can I simply upcast and save the entity?

If I create a new instance of the base entity, everything works just fine.

Comment: This is a common scenario, where properties of the class used in a controller are different from the properties of the class to be saved in the database. The most common solution is to not use inheritance and just create a new instance of the database entity, copying over the needed properties. It will set you up for success not only for your particular problem, but for other scenarios as well.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Is there a "not so common solution"? I mean, how can I use inheritance and save the base entity. Is it even possible?

Comment: there are 3 types of inheritance supported in EF. You can read up on those at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Don't inherit entities (in EF6 it might cause other unexpected side effects), use DTOs/ViewModels etc. with containment instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Devil, this only covers "downcasting" - I need "upcating"!

I wrote a converter. I could not believe, that I have to do this´, but now it is working just fine! Thx, for your help!

```
public static T ConvertToBase<T>(Object extended) {
  if(extended == null) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Parameter extended was passed null!");
  }

  if(extended.GetType().BaseType != typeof(T)) {
    throw new ArgumentException($"Parameter extended does not inherit base type '{typeof(T).FullName}'");
  }

  PropertyInfo[] baseProperties = extended.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties();
  Object baseInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(extended.GetType().BaseType);

  foreach(PropertyInfo basePropertyInfo in baseProperties) {
    basePropertyInfo.SetValue(baseInstance, basePropertyInfo.GetValue(extended));
  }

  return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(baseInstance, typeof(T));
}
```